# Where do I get a helicopter for Lester's mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

On mission where Lester ask you to get documents on the top of a building, you need a helicopter.

My partner and I went in the airport, top of the hospital, airport in the middle off the map, south beach and we didn't see any choppers.

My partner called in a helicopter from his contact list but we couldn't control it. We got killed while the chopper was standing just above the building.

For that mission, do we need to own a chopper or can we find one on the map?

Comment: you don't actually need a chopper, you can climb the ladder (I believe it's on the crane) but it takes forever and if you die you're basically out of luck.  I would recommend getting a chopper as per @CaulynDarr's answer

Comment: @turbo I tried that at first.  They see you just as you get to the top of the crane and will shoot you.   You'll die before ever getting to the building.

Comment: @CaulynDarr it's not easy or recommended, but if you truly can't get a helicopter, what else can you do?

Comment: Managed to do this mission without a helicopter but it was ridiculous. Climbed the ladder for absolutely ages, avoided getting shot and then had to parachute off the crane onto the building. The parachuting killed the other three people in my group so I had to take out two helicopters by myself with a hand gun. Then because you're not supposed to get on to the building that way, you can't get back down, so had to hobble across the crane to get back to the ladder. It was ridiculous and took forever, so yeah, get a helicopter if you can -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mission is a bit frustrating if you don't own your own chopper.  It may be that the devs forgot to enable the construction site elevators.

Luckily there is a way to get around this at lower levels.

First call in the Merryweather chopper for a pickup.  When it lands, shoot the pilot in the head.  You now have a chopper to use.  Next either land the chopper on a nearby tall building's roof and clear the upper floors of the construction site with sniper rifles

Or go to Fort Zancudo and steal a attack helicopter. They still spawn there during missions.

Otherwise save up the cash and buy a personal chopper.

Comment: By "lower levels" you mean 30 and above, so this is no help to anyone at a level < 30.

Comment: @Archer, well it is a level 25 mission, not an unreasonable solution, but does not cover all cases

Comment: @Archer Then go break into the Fort on foot.  Or save up $$$$ and buy your own Maverick.  The answer is factually correct, don't down vote just because you don't like it.

Comment: It's factually correct, yes, but not an answer to the question that was asked, hence the down-vote :)

Comment: @Archer How so?  The question was where they can find a helicopter for this mission.  I told them all of the available ways how, with the bonus on how to actually use one to complete the mission.

Comment: You told him how to get the helicopter if you're level 30 or above.  This should be a comment at best.

Comment: @Archer Not to drag this out further, but if there is no other way...  If you feel the answer is partial, that's a good reason to not up-vote it.  You could also provide a better answer or edit it yourself if you have enough rep.

Comment: I've added the < level 30 answer as suggested :)

Comment: I have to think as GTAV. Need something ? Steal it!

Answer (score 2):

If you're below level 30 then you can still get a helicopter for missions, but most of the usual places are empty.  I used the helipad you can see on this map...

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-WbBGryzK8q0/Ujomx_u8kXI/AAAAAAAAO34/t3wVfDworOU/s1600/My+Great+Game+-+My+Great+Capture+-+2013-09-18+03-16-14.png]

It's annoying to get a helicopter there, but you can do it.  If you park up at the road and then survey the area with a decent mid-to-long range weapon then you'll probably see a helicopter, normally hovering above a helipad.  Let the pilot land and then shoot him from where you are.  This is the bit that's annoying.  If you get too close then he'll take off and then he's gone for good.

If that does happen, or if there is no helicopter when you get there then just drive off and come back, in order to refresh the NPCs in the area.

Most of the time I've got a helicopter first time with this method, but sometimes I've driven off and come back again several times and had nothing.

As mentioned in CaulynDarr's answer, it's much easier to call MerryWeather and kill the pilot so I'd recommend that, but if you're below level 30 then you don't have that option.

Comment: Thanks @turbo.  I didn't think it would resize the image nicely, hence the link instead.  That's much better :)

Comment: Yeah I wasn't going to do it if it stretched the screen, but it looks pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

At rank 10, every time I have gone to the Eastern end of the large airfield (South of the lake), I have found a Maverick on the helipad. I have never failed to find one there. I assume that as your rank increases, the helicopter spawning there may change.

Also good as a getaway vehicle for robbing stores!

Comment: Those spawn points are only available in free mode.  In missions they are empty.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the clarification. I assume it isn't possible to obtain the vehicle before starting the mission?

Comment: No, it will start you free falling in mid air if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a helicopter for this mission at all... there's a container right near the entrance to the airport that you can use to jump the fence if you're in a vehicle. It doesn't need to be super fast either, it's an easy jump.